# Error en recorrido de array

Tags: jquery

Tengo un script largo y complejo (para mi digamos), en el que tengo un algoritmo sbre un array JSON obtenido con php, que es un listado de productos.

LA unica parate que me da error es en mostrarsublista, esta funcion toma un array, un desde y un hasta y muestra la tabla html con dicho contenido.

El algoritmo o lo que quise hacer fue filtrar por categoria y subcategoria y a su vez busqueda por nombre. Se que me complique un poco pero sino podria dejar la busqueda por texto incremental sobre los 5000 registros, y los combos solo para filtrar y recorrer con el mouse. Pero queria pedirles ayuda a ver si soluciono.

el codigo que da error es el siguiente:

```js
function mostrarsublista(data,desde,hasta){

        $("#resultado tbody").empty();
 
    for (var i = desde; i < hasta; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].subcategoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].aliiva + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+data[i].idproducto+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado tbody");                 
       
    
               
            }
};
```

Y el error que obtengo es:
**TypeError: data[i] is undefined**
Por otro lado..hice un consoe.log(data) y el array llega perfecto.

Comment: OK..voy a actualizar la pregunta

Comment: Verifica si existen tantos `datos[i]` como `desdes` hay. No sé si me he explicado. Puede que haya menos `datas` que `desdes`, por eso te dice que es `undefined`, porque no existe.

Comment: perdon pero no seria el hasta? osea tengo paginacion y el minimo es hasta 200( de 0 a 200), pero actualmente en la bd tengo 5 registros de prueba

Comment: Sí perdón, hasta el `hasta`. ¿El `hasta` qué contiene?¿Y el `data`?

Comment: Gracias amigo..puse un condicional, donde hasta se iguala a la longitud de data y se soluciono

Comment: De nada :). Pondré la solución en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el ciclo es recorrido más veces que `data` existen. Para solucionarlo comprueba con un condicional la longitud del `data` para que solo entre a la condición si es menor o igual a `hasta`.